# How to access data from ajax result (json object) using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So I have this function that gets the user details via UUID;

```
function getUserDetails(uuid){

    $.ajax({
      url:'http://localhost/hrms/controller/php/getUserDetails.php',
      method: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: { uuid: uuid },
      success:function(result){
        console.log(result);
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, error){
        if(xhr.status == 401){
          toastr.error(xhr.responseText);
        }
      }
    });
}
```

which give me the result of

[AJAX RESULT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEvxL.png)

Now I wonder how to access that data. The function is from different js page. How can I throw the json result to another js page?

Im using JQUERY. Thanks and more powers.

Comment: what do you mean "The function is from different js page" ?

Comment: I have functions.js where the function is written. And Im accessing the function through another js file like index.js.

Comment: I try using array callback but im getting undefined result when I try to console.log. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: still don't get what you saying

Comment: First.js 

`function functionname(){...}`

Second.js

`var data = functionname()`

Something like this.

Comment: in which file this `getUserDetails` function contain ?

Comment: GetUserDetails() function is written in functions.js. Im trying to access the ajax result in my other js files.

Comment: can you add your how you tried to access ?

Comment: I cant really access cause im not getting any result. But im using this 

`var flag = true;

if(flag){
 var data = getUserDetails(uuid);
 console.log(data);
}
else{
 flag = false;
}` 

code

Comment: I think its in the ajax callback. I dont know how to throw ajax result to another js file. So im not getting any result in the data variable.

Comment: uhh i see what you trying to do, ok i'll post an answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you use ajax it takes some time to return the data form server to client, so you can use promise or callbacks:

***Callbacks:***

**function.js**

```
function getUserDetails(uuid, callback){

    $.ajax({
      url:'http://localhost/hrms/controller/php/getUserDetails.php',
      method: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: { uuid: uuid },
      success:function(result){
        callback(result);
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, error){
        if(xhr.status == 401){
          toastr.error(xhr.responseText);
        }
      }
    });
 }
```

**index.js**

```
getUserDetails(uuid, function(data){
    console.log(data); 
});
```

***Promises***

**function.js**

```
function getUserDetails(uuid){
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    $.ajax({
      url:'http://localhost/hrms/controller/php/getUserDetails.php',
      method: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: { uuid: uuid },
      success:function(result){
        resolve(result);
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, error){
        if(xhr.status == 401){
          toastr.error(xhr.responseText);
        }
        const reason = new Error('Error');
        reject(reason);
      }
    });
   });
 }
```

**index.js**

```
getUserDetails(uuid).then(function(data){
   console.log(data); 
});
```